# Do the different game modes moving on the map change anything?

Tags: for-honor

When the 3 game modes change places on the map does it affect anything? Like if Breach switches from top left to top right do my troops get a bonus when deployed on top right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each map operates independently from each other, so there is no change in troop bonuses. If you place troops to top frontline on the map and then play breach in the bottom-right (A knight player here), troops do not change bonuses.